# Why do we use "a" in the first sentence?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Why do we use "a" in the first sentence?

> Kevin works in **a hospital**. He operates on people.

> Sarah looks after patients in **hospital**.

Note: the two examples from the same book: English Grammar in Use

Comment: Does the book say anything about this? (It’s my understand that the article is dropped before _hospital_ much more frequently in BrE than AmE.)

Comment: You can omit the article for a noun like "hospital", "prison", and "school". You do this when you focus more on the main purpose of the instutition rather than the building itself.

Comment: @J.R. Unfortunately no, the book doesn't describe it.

Comment: @user178049 any reference, please?

Comment: @Shannak I thought I read that in *Oxford Guide to English Grammar*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In British English, **in hospital** means "under hospital care" or "receiving hospital care". For that reason, we would say:

> She looks after patients in hospital.

That is, *She looks after patients (who are) under hospital care.*

But when we want to refer to the *place* as distinct from the care provided there:

> Kevin works in **a** hospital.

Kevin is not under hospital care. He works there.

In American English, the phrase that means "under hospital care" is **in the hospital**.

> She had a car accident.
>   -- Is she going to be OK?
>   She's in the hospital, with broken ribs and lacerations.

When speakers of AmE say *in the hospital* in such contexts, they do not mean a *particular* hospital or an *aforementioned* hospital. They mean *under hospital care*.

Comment: any recommended reference, I need to read more about it

Answer (score -2):

Kevin works in a hospital. Kevin is an employee of that hospital.

Sarah looks after patients in hospital. Not at home, or other place.